# How to find the recurrence relation from a given polynomial?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, recurrence-relations, formal-power-series

Consider the formal power series: $A(x)=\sum a_nx^n$.

and

$A(x)= \frac{8+14x-50x^2}{1-7x^2+6x^3}$

I am trying to derive a recurrence relation, Is there a general method for doing it?

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by a recurrence relation? The relation between $A(x+1)$ and $A(x)$?

Comment: @Demosthene I'm guessing some formula for $a_n$ in terms of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Rational_generating_function

Comment: It would come from the coefficients in the denominator:$a_n = 7a_{n-2} - 6a_{n-3}$ for $n\geq 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suppose that you want $$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_i x^i$$ So, let us mutliply both sides by the denominator $$8+14x-50x^2=(1-7x^2+6x^3)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_i x^i$$ Now, decompose the product  $$8+14x-50x^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_i x^i-7\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_i x^{i+2}+6\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_i x^{i+3}$$ So, for the constant term $$8=a_0$$ For the first power of $x$ $$14=a_1$$ For the $x^2$ term $$-50=a_2-7a_0$$ So, to summarize $a_0=8,a_1=14,a_2=6$.

Now, for any power $n\gt 2$, the term $x^n$ is zero in the lhs. So, $$0=a_n-7a_{n-2}+6a_{n-3}$$ So, the recurrence is $$a_n=7a_{n-2}-6a_{n-3}$$ This is exactly what is described in the Wikipedia page and the same procedure applies for all cases like your one (just identify the coefficients for a given power of $x$ on each side).

Is this clear ? If not, just post.

Comment: You are welcome ! For your training, make another of your choice. This is the general method : simple and systematic ! Make one and add to your post to show that you understood the way to do it. Cheers :-)